# Segmentation fault when alphabetically sorting an array of pointers to chars in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Say I want to lexicographically sort an array, `**x`, and I'm attempting to use an sort:

```
char **x
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(x); i++) {
        if (strcmp(x[i], x[i + 1]) > 0) {
           char *temp = x[i];
           x[i] = x[i + 1];
           x[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Of course, I'm also looping through it too. Each time I attempt to sort, however, I get a segmentation fault. It prints fine when I don't sort it. What could be causing the sort to fail?

Comment: `sizeof(x)` does not return the size of the array but of a pointer. And would it be the size then it should be minus 1 because you index with `i + 1`

Comment: What's the type of `x`? `sizeof(x)` is definitely wrong, but wrong in different ways depending on whether `x` is an array or pointer.

Comment: 'sizeof(x)' what does that mean?

Comment: @interjay It is `char **x` type

Comment: Then you need to use the actual size (stored in another variable) instead. By the way, this code is not an insertion sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work without knowing the size of the array. When you call sizeof(x) you are in fact returning sizeof(char**) which is 8 on most 64 bit systems and NOT the number of elements in the array.

You need to know the number of elements in the array and than modify you code to do this:

```
int x_length = <number of elements in x>
char **x
for (i = 0; i < x_length; i++) {
    if (strcmp(x[i], x[i + 1]) > 0) {
       char *temp = x[i];
       x[i] = x[i + 1];
       x[i + 1] = temp;
    }
}
```